# Time complexity of ranked batch-mode sampling query strategy

Tags: time-complexity, active-learning

I am performing different Active Learning experiments using several query strategies. One of the query strategies is the "Ranked batch-mode sampling" from [Python's modAL library](https://modal-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/examples/ranked_batch_mode.html), which is an implementation of [Cardoso et al.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0020025516313949)’s ranked batch-mode sampling.

The query strategy computes the scores for each data instance of the unlabelled pool $x \in \mathcal{D}_{\mathcal{U}}$ using the formula

$$
score(x) = \alpha (1 - sim(x, \mathcal{D}_{\mathcal{L}})) + (1 - \alpha)\phi(x),
$$

where $\alpha = \frac{n}{n + p}$,  $n$ is the size of $D_{\mathcal{U}}$, $p$ is the size of $\mathcal{D}_{\mathcal{L}}$, $\phi(x)$ is the uncertainty of predictions for $x$, and $sim$ is a similarity function, for instance cosine similarity.

The similarity function measures how well the space is explored near $x$, and, thus, will give a higher score to those data instances that are less similar to the ones that have already been labelled.

In each iteration, the scores are computed for all the instances in the unlabelled pool. The instance with the highest score is removed from the pool and the scores are recalculated until $B$ instances have been selected.

My computation of the time complexity is as follows:

The time complexity of computing cosine similarity between two vectors of size $d$ is $O(d)$. Therefore, the time complexity of computing the cosine similarity between the every unlabelled sample $x \in D_{\mathcal{U}}$ and all the labelled samples in $\mathcal{D}_{\mathcal{L}}$ is $O(n \cdot p \cdot d)$. Overall, the  time complexity of querying a batch of size $B$ is $O(B \cdot n \cdot p \cdot d)$.

Are my computations correct? A representation of the time required by this query strategy vs. the size of the labelled dataset $D_{\mathcal{L}}$ show an exponential curve, not a linear curve.